# difference between firebase .on("value") and .once("value")

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

On updating a child firebase runs one more time when using `".once"` to fetch the value from firebase and add a new row in application. But when using `".on"` the code works on updating a child But not working on adding a new child as it removes the row from application though it adds to the firebase But we are able to view that only when we refreshes the page. My question here is what to how to fetch new data from firebase after adding or updating.

Comment: Using `once()` gets the value from the database once, while using `on()` continues to listen for changes to the data until you call `off()`. If you have a problem with the behavior of these in your code, share the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: once() is like addListenerForSingleValueEvent and on() is like valueeventlistener in android

Comment: It is just I have added on('child_added') and once('value'). Now whenever I add a child first child_added events hit and then once('value'). Hence it is creating two rows in my view for the same child.

Comment: I know this is an old question... But this may help anyone looking for an answer to this issue. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/3NGhVYC_2Kw