# Waiting for all firebase call to finish with map function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm fetching my user data and the map function is called several times for each user. I want to wait until all data was pushed to the array and then manipulate the data. I tried using Promise.all() but it didn't work. 
How can I wait for this map function to finish before continuing?

Needless to say that the array `user_list_temp` is empty when printed inside the Promise.all().

```
 const phone_list_promise_1 = await arrWithKeys.map(async (users,i) => {
      return firebase.database().ref(`/users/${users}`)
          .on('value', snapshot => {
              user_list_temp.push(snapshot.val());
              console.log(snapshot.val());
            })
        }
  );

Promise.all(phone_list_promise_1).then( () => console.log(user_list_temp) )
```

I changed the code to this but I still get a wrong output

```
Promise.all(arrWithKeys.map(async (users,i) => {
      const eventRef = db.ref(`users/${users}`);
      await eventRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        const value = snapshot.val();
        console.log(value);
        phone_user_list[0][users].name = value.name;
        phone_user_list[0][users].photo = value.photo;
      })
      console.log(phone_user_list[0]); 
      user_list_temp.push(phone_user_list[0]);
    }

  ));
    console.log(user_list_temp); //empty  array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `async/await` with [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47713500/5508175)

This is how I usually make a `Promise.all`

```
const db = firebase.database();
let user_list_temp = await Promise.all(arrWithKeys.map(async (users,i) => {
    const eventRef = db.ref(`users/${users}`);
    const snapshot = await eventref.once('value');
    const value = snapshot.value();
    return value;
  })
);
```

This article gives a fairly good explanation of using `Promise.all` with `async/await` https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

Here is how I would refactor your new code snippet so that you are not mixing `promises` and `async/await`

```
let user_list_temp = await Promise.all(arrWithKeys.map(async (users,i) => {
  const eventRef = db.ref(`users/${users}`);
  const snapshot=  await eventRef.once('value');
  const value = snapshot.val();
  console.log(value);
  phone_user_list[0][users].name = value.name;    // should this be hardcoded as 0?
  phone_user_list[0][users].photo = value.photo;  // should this be hardcoded as 0?
  console.log(phone_user_list[0]); 
  return phone_user_list[0];        // should this be hardcoded as 0?
  })
);
console.log(user_list_temp);
```

---

Here is a simple example that uses fetch, instead of firebase:

```
async componentDidMount () {
  let urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/4'
  ];
  let results = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
  }));
  alert(JSON.stringify(results))
}
```

Comment: must have been the late hour. I tested it again and it didn't work like I thought it did... I've updated the post. Do you happen to know why I still get an empty array?

Comment: You’re mixing `promises` and `async/await` you shouldn’t do both inside a `Promise.all`

Comment: I also missed out an `await` in front of the `Promise.all`

Comment: I tried the new firebase option and that didn't work. I changed the .on to .once and it worked as I wanted. Do you know why?

Comment: I’m not that familiar with firebase. I just used your code and created the `Promise.all` around it. I’m glad that it is working now.

Comment: Using once() gets the value from the database once, while using on() continues to listen for changes to the data until you call off(). From a comment in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572171/difference-between-firebase-onvalue-and-oncevalue?noredirect=1&lq=1. The comments author is an engineer at google who works on firebase

Comment: @Andrew You're using `.map` like a `.forEach` which is kinda wrong. Just return the value from the callback and it will get included in the map result. Plus there's no benefit in mapping using an `async` callback. Just accumulate the promises and pass them to `Promise.all` to `await` them.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you might consider revising your code to use a regular `for..of` loop, with a nested promise per user that resolves when the snapshot/value for that user is available as shown:

```
const user_list_temp = [];

/*
Use regular for..of loop to iterate values
*/
for(const user of arrWithKeys) {

    /*
    Use await on a new promise object for this user that
    resolves with snapshot value when value recieved for
    user
    */
    const user_list_item = await (new Promise((resolve) => {

        firebase.database()
        .ref(`/users/${users}`)
        .on('value', snapshot => {

            /*
            When value recieved, resolve the promise for
            this user with val()
            */    
            resolve(snapshot.val());
        });
    }));

    /*
    Add value for this user to the resulting user_list_item
    */
    user_list_temp.push(user_list_item);
}

console.log(user_list_temp);
```

This code assumes that the enclosing function is defined as an asynchronous method with the `async` keyword, seeing that the `await` keyword is used in the `for..of` loop. Hope that helps!